# What is the meaning of the return value of e.GetPosition(...) in DragLeave EventArgs?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

If I write an event handler for the DragLeave event in WPF, I can call `e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement)` on the DragEventArgs e of the event.
I expected to get a Point relative to the control (sender) just left, but it's not the case. Instead the returned Point looks more like a point relative to another control to be entered immediately after leaving this control.

So how should I interpret this return value of `e.GetPosition(...)`?

EDIT:

Ok, yesterday I implemented a sample app proving, that the value returned by `e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender)` can't be correct. See below:

My assumption is, that the returned position is related to the control element entered directly after leaving the current one no matter, if I call `e.GetPosition(...)` with the currently left control as sender.
`MainWindow.xaml:`

```
<Window ...>
    <Canvas Background="AliceBlue" AllowDrop="True">
        <Rectangle AllowDrop="True"
                   Canvas.Left="175"
                   Canvas.Top="175"
                   Width="100"
                   Height="100"
                   Fill="Tan"
                   PreviewMouseMove="Rectangle_OnPreviewMouseMove"
                   PreviewDragLeave="Rectangle_OnPreviewDragLeave"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="GetPositionValue"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

As you see, it's a simple `Rectangle` and a `TextBox` inside of a `Canvas`.

The `Rectangle` is used as a preferable simple, dragable control.

The `TextBox` and the `Canvas` are to visualize the returned position.

For Drag'n'Drop the `Rectangle` has `PreviewMouseMove` and `PreviewDragLeave` events handled in code behind as follows:

`MainWindow.xaml.cs:`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Rectangle_OnPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, new DataObject("foo"), DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }

    private void Rectangle_OnPreviewDragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var givenPoint = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);
        Canvas.SetLeft(this.GetPositionValue, givenPoint.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(this.GetPositionValue, givenPoint.Y);
        this.GetPositionValue.Text = givenPoint2.ToString();
    }
}
```

The `PreviewMouseMove` handler is just for initializing the Drag'n'Drop.

The `PreviewDragLeave` handler calls the `e.GetPosition(...)` method with the sender (here the Rectangle) and stores the value in `givenPoint`.

To show, that the `givenPoint` is the mouse position related to the newly entered control (here the `Canvas`), I not only set the `Text` of the `TextBox` with the `givenPoint` coordinates, but also positioned the `TextBox` to that position in the `Canvas`.

Start the app and do the following:
Press and hold left mouse button inside the `Rectangle` and then drag it towards the `Canvas`. On leaving the `Rectangle` with the mouse pointer, the `TextBox` with the `givenPoint` coordinates will appear right under the current mouse pointer position.

---

*So the point given by the `DragLeave` event must be related to `Canvas`, even if I implemented it to be related to the sender (`Rectangle`).*

---

*PS: It's a simple app just to show the point. Please ignore any kind of bad style like 'not catching exeptions', etc..*

Comment: `sender` is always the element where the event handler is attached. You probably want to use `e.Source` or `e.OriginalSource`. Besides that, you should not use the `as` operator without checking the result for `null`. Write `e.GetPosition((IInputElement)e.OriginalSource)`.

Comment: @Clemens: No I don't. I expected the return value of `e.GetPosition(...)` to be a Point out of the bounds of the sender/source/originalsource like a negative coordinates or coordinates greater than it's actual width, but it isn't. Today I wrote a demonstrator, which showed that the Point returned by DragLeave is exactly the same point which was return by DragEnter of the next entered control.

Comment: I've done a lot of drag and drop in WPF. I tested this out and this one has me stumped too. I've never had to use `GetPosition` from `DragLeave` so I've never run into this problem, but I can reproduce it just as described and I have no idea why this happens. You get equally strange results if you try `GetPosition(this)` instead of `GetPosition(sender)`. There are (annoying) work-arounds I know of, but it's still very strange that this happens. It might even be a bug in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

While it is technically not an answer, I think I can at least provide an explanation to what you're seeing. It seems to be an API desing/documentation problem in WPF, since they fail to communicate this aspect of the underlying OLE drag and drop system.

If you compare [IDropTarget::DragOver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nf-oleidl-idroptarget-dragover) and [IDropTarget::DragLeave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nf-oleidl-idroptarget-dragleave), you'll see that the latter has no parameters, whereas the former has the parameter `pt`, which is

> A POINTL structure containing the current cursor coordinates in screen coordinates.

`System.Windows.OleDropTarget` "deals" with it like this:

```
int MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.IOleDropTarget.OleDragLeave()
{
    if (this._lastTarget != null)
    {
        int num = 0;
        try
        {
            this.RaiseDragEvent(DragDrop.DragLeaveEvent, 0, ref num, this._lastTarget, new Point(0, 0));
        }
        finally
        {
            this._lastTarget = null;
            this._dataObject = null;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notice the `new Point(0, 0)` in particular.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dragdrop.dragleave?view=netframework-4.8) only hints that this event only exists for a particular purpose:

> You typically handle this event to undo any changes that you made in
>   the DragEnter event handler.

There exists a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/635146/dragleave-event-delivering-wrong-value-for-egetpos.html) about this.

Now as for the solution, I recommend doing all position based work in the DragOver event, as that will be close enough. You could also remember the position from the last DragOver event, and use that directly, or find the closest edge point to that in DragLeave. Another option could be to use some native interop calls to get the mouse position. Note that Mouse.GetPosition [will not work](https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/01/08/729-mouse-getposition-doesnt-work-while-dragging/).